# How to create Image File from Data Url in Servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I'm going to create image file from data posted from a web page. The data is in Data Url format like this: `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU....`.

the servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String line = null;
    File image = new File("D:\\image.jpg");
    FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(image);

    BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();

    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
        stream.write(line.getBytes());
    }
    stream.flush();
    stream.close();
    response.getWriter().print("ok");
}
```

the data url in browsers works correctly.
but the created image on my system is corrupted. any idea?

Comment: I'll leave the servlet experts to provide an answer, but almost certainly you're missing some base64-decoding there. You seem to be reading the data as a string, then writing the bytes of that string to disk. Instead, you should be base64-decoding the string, then writing those bytes to disk. I don't know enough about servlets to know whether you need to further dissect your data before you can decode it.

Comment: Second thing is that you create a JPEG file but in your URL the content type `image/png` is shown, so you should also create a PNG file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove "data:image/jpeg;base64," from the dataURI and decode the dataURI .

```
public void saveImage(String imageURI) {
BufferedImage image = null;
String blobString=imageString.replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", "");
byte[] byteArray = Base64.getDecoder().decode(blobString);
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
try {
    image = ImageIO.read(bis);
    File file = new File("/home/rakesh/Vinay/a.jpeg");
    ImageIO.write(image, "jpeg", file);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

The format is encoded, in this case base64. You can use [URLDecodor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html) to decode the stream.